# Prototyping a flight path over a Google Map

Tags: html, google-maps, web

Pretend that you're in an airplane. You can access a Google Map that shows what you're flying over. The map moves with the plane.

I'd like to prototype this. How can I go about doing this?

My thoughts are to take a very high res picture of the flight path. Using some unknown method, I could "zoom in" on part of the image. Every time a new frame is drawn, the map picture should move x pixels to the left... or something like that.

Comment: If you're taking images, be careful you're not violating the terms of service of the Maps API. You should read that very carefully.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is not an image, it's a polyline which defines the route.

You'll be able to "walk" this line by using the defined waypoints and a little bit calculation.

The moving of the map may be achieved by using `map.setCenter(currentPosition)`

Docs: http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#Polylines